# jQuery: Show a DIV with a VAR as CLASS

Tags: javascript, jquery, var, rel

I'm trying to link some DIVs together by putting the class of DIV#2 into REL of DIV#1.

I can't find out why this doesn't work. If I html() it, it will write the correct thing.

I have made an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6Q2G/6/

Can you see whats wrong???

Comment: The `rel` attribute doesn't exist on the `div` element, and on elements where it does exist it describes the *type* of relationship, not what the relationship is with. Stick to using HTML instead of made up markup languages.

Comment: You can use data attributes instead of the `rel`, which is not valid, like pointed out by @David. In the markup you can put `data-linkedto="divclass"`, and read it with `$(selector).data('linkedto')` with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/n6Q2G/7/

I changed it to `$("div." + sucessDialog).show();`

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var sucessDialog = $('#dialogs > div:visible').attr('rel');
    $('#dialogs > div:visible').slideUp("slow");

    //just do a filter with divs that have that added class
    $("div." + sucessDialog).show();
});
```

Comment: @KennethB does for me. One slides up and the other is shown. Doesn't work for you?